# How to join two identical tables together in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are three tables from my database schema:

```
-- Table where I store authors
SELECT author_id, first_name, last_name FROM author;
╔═══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ author_id ║ first_name ║ last_name ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║         1 ║     Ernest ║ Hemingway ║
║         2 ║       Walt ║   Whitman ║
║         3 ║       Mark ║     Twain ║
║       ... ║        ... ║       ... ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝

-- Junction-table to keep track of books and their respective authors
SELECT book_id, author_id FROM book_author;
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ book_id ║ author_id ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║      37 ║         1 ║
║      37 ║         2 ║
║     ... ║       ... ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝

-- Temporary table to store, once again, books and their respective authors
-- but only for updating book purposes. The table is identical in its structure
-- to the book_author table
SELECT book_id, author_id FROM temp_book_author;
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ book_id ║ author_id ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║      37 ║         3 ║
║     ... ║       ... ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

Now, I can use this query down below to get the result that follows:

```
SET    @BOOK_ID = 37;
SELECT @BOOK_ID AS book_id,
       a.last_name,
       a.first_name
FROM   book_author AS ba
       LEFT JOIN author AS a
              ON ba.author_id = a.author_id
WHERE  book_id = @BOOK_ID;
╔═════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ book_id ║ first_name ║ last_name ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║      37 ║     Ernest ║ Hemingway ║
║      37 ║       Walt ║   Whitman ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Here's what I would like to achieve: I need to add that row (or rows if there were more of them) which is associated with the book that has an ID of 37 from the **temp_book_author** table to the selection above, or, if you will, kind of make the two tables, **book_author** and **temp_book_author** that is, one table as though they were one table to start with:

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ book_id ║ first_name ║ last_name ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║      37 ║     Ernest ║ Hemingway ║
║      37 ║       Walt ║   Whitman ║
║      37 ║       Mark ║     Twain ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Do you just need to `INSERT INTO BOOK_AUTHOR (book_id,author_id) SELECT book_id,Author_id FROm temp_book_author;` or did I misunderstand

Comment: @Scotch: Please do add it as an answer so that it may possibly be accepted.

Comment: @RoneyMichael Too late:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a UNION:

```
SET    @BOOK_ID = 37;
SELECT @BOOK_ID AS book_id,
       a.last_name,
       a.first_name
FROM   (SELECT * FROM book_author
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM temp_book_author) AS ba
       LEFT JOIN author AS a
              ON ba.author_id = a.author_id
WHERE  book_id = @BOOK_ID;
```

You can also create a table that automatically merges two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE union_book_author (book_id int, author_id int)
ENGINE = MERGE
UNION = (book_author, temp_book_author);
```

You can then use `union_book_author` in a query.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Scotch's comment that ideally you should insert the data from temp_book_author into book_author and then select from this table, but if there are reasons why you don't want to do this, then you need to use the sql command '**union**'.

```
SET    @BOOK_ID = 37;
SELECT @BOOK_ID AS book_id, a.last_name, a.first_name
FROM   book_author AS ba 
LEFT JOIN author AS a ON ba.author_id = a.author_id
WHERE  book_id = @BOOK_ID
UNION
select t.book_id, a1.last_name, a1.firstname
from temp_book_author as t
left join author as a1 on t.author_id = a1.author_id
where t.book_id = @BOOK_ID
```